# How to fix the following exception com.google.appengine.api.labs.modules.ModulesException: Instance id unavailable

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to port over a pre-1.8.x Google App Engine application to `1.8.7`

And I am getting the following errors on my Local Development Server as well as when I deploy my application to GAE on every call to a URL.

I see that other people are suffering from the same issue but none of the posts I could find on the Internet had an actual solution.

```
Nov 12, 2013 9:05:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter doDirectRequest
[INFO] FINEST: request to specific module instance: -1.default
[INFO] Nov 12, 2013 9:05:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter getCurrentModuleInstance
[INFO] FINE: Exception getting module instance
[INFO] com.google.appengine.api.labs.modules.ModulesException: Instance id unavailable
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.labs.modules.ModulesServiceImpl.getCurrentInstanceId(ModulesServiceImpl.java:68)
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with GAE 1.8.8. Two observations: 1. The exception is logged with Level.FINE, so perhaps this is why it wasn't observed earlier (could have happened in my case), 2. servlet continues execution afterwards, so maybe this exception can be ignored? Anyway, did you arrive at a (better) explanation/solution meanwhile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue (I encountered it with 1.8.9), but can be ignored.

[Issue 10412: Skeleton web application's doGet throws "ModulesException: Instance id unavailable"](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10412)

Answer (score 5):

As Tom answered correctly, this is not an issue, but it is April 2015 and this exception still fills the logs of my devserver!

Add the following to your `logging.properties` to keep this noise out of your logs when running in the development server.

```
# turn off error com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesException: Instance id unavailable errors in devserver
com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.level = SEVERE
```